# How to create a string interpreter in python that takes propositions and return an answer based on a given dictionary keys?

Tags: python, recursion, functional-programming, string-interpolation

So after 2 days of struggling with this problem i gave up. You are given two inputs the first one is a lists that contains propositions and the second one is a dictionary.

example:

```
arg= [<prop1>, "OPERATOR", <prop2>]

dicti= {<prop1>: key1, <prop2394>: key2394,<prop2>:key2}
```

the following is a possible input:

```
    arg= [<prop1>, "OPERATOR (AND OR )",
[ "NOT" ,["NOT",<prop2>,"OPERATOR"[<prop2>, "OPERATOR", <prop3>]]]
```

I am betting that the problem wont be solved without using double recursion. This is my attempt to solve the problem, i started with base case that the input is a "*flat*" list which means 1D list that has no lists as elements of the the list. The program should not return boolean values but return `true` or `false` which are given in the dictionary.

```
def interpret(arg, keys ):
    if not arg :
        return "false"
    elif not arg and not keys:
        return "false"
    elif not keys and isinstance(arg,list):
        return "true"
    elif isinstance(arg[0],list):
        return interperter(arg[0:],keys)
    else:
        trueCnr=0
        for i in range(len(arg)):
            if arg[i] in keys and keys[arg[i]]=="true":
                if isinstance (arg[i], list):
                    if("NOT" in arg):
                        indx= arg.index("NOT")
                        keys[arg[indx+1]]= "true" if keys[arg[indx+1]]=="true" else "false"
                    trueCnr+=1
        print(trueCnr)
        if trueCnr==len(arg)-1 and "AND" in arg: return "true"
        elif trueCnr!= 0 and "OR" in arg: return "true"
        else: return "false"

print (interpret(["door_open", "AND", ["NOT","cat_gone"]], {"door_open" : "false", "cat_gone" : "true", "cat_asleep" : "true"} ))
```

My question is how do i proceed from here.

Comment: What is a proposition?

Comment: What do you want the output looks like? What are the rules to transform the input to output?

Comment: @HaiVu in a form of ´"true"`or `"false"` not the boolean `True´ or `False`

Comment: @ScottHunter a proposition is  a statement or assertion that expresses a judgement or opinion ---- Google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use recursion.  Define a function `eval(prop, keys)` to evaluate the proposition.  Then match the proposition with a case.  For example,

```
['prop1', 'AND', 'prop2']
```

If you see the above, you would evaluate it as

```
return eval(prop[:1], keys) and eval(prop[1:], keys)
```

A more complex example:

```
[ "NOT" ,["NOT",'prop2',"OPERATOR"['prop2', "OPERATOR", 'prop3']]]
```

would look like

```
return not eval(prop[1], keys)
```

The thing to realize is that at each call to `eval`, exactly one operator has precedence.  Your job is to recognize which operator that is, then pass the rest of the list off to other `eval` calls to handle.

In pseudocode:

```
def eval(prop, keys):
  if not prop:
    return False
  if prop is a key:
    return keys[prop]
  if prop has a binary operator:
    return eval(stuff before operator) operator eval(stuff after operator)
  if prop has unary operator:
    return operator eval(stuff after operator)
```

Also, notice that you must return booleans `True` and `False` not strings `'True'` and '`False`'

Comment: The point here is to return `"true"` and `"false"` not the boolean values, and no your pseudocode didn't solve it